Handling 411 Length Required Error in Axios POST Request in React Signup Component
I was building a payment app (paytm app) using react, express, mongodb, mongoose, tailwind where i made separate components and pages for the frontend. but when i was just trying to hit backend from my signup page frontend to backend. then i'm getting this as error.

here is my signup page code:
import { useState } from "react"
import { ButtonWarning } from "../components/BottomWarning"
import { Button } from "../components/Button"
import { Heading } from "../components/Heading"
import { InputBox } from "../components/InputBox"
import { SubHeading } from "../components/SubHeading"
import axios from "axios"

export const Signup = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    return <div className="bg-slate-300 flex justify-center h-screen">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
            <div className="rounded-lg bg-white p-2 w-80 text-center h-max px-4">
                <Heading label={"Sign Up"} />
                <SubHeading label={"Enter your information to create an account"} />
                <InputBox onChange={e => {
                    setFirstName(e.target.value);
                }} label={"First Name"} placeholder={"Ratnesh"}/>
                <InputBox onChange={e => {
                    setLastName(e.target.value);
                }} label={"Last Name"} placeholder={"Kumar"}/>
                <InputBox onChange={e => {
                    setUsername(e.target.value);
                }} label={"Email"} placeholder={"ratnesh@gmail.com"}/>
                <InputBox onChange={e => {
                    setPassword(e.target.value);
                }} label={"Password"} placeholder={"Aa!@123"} />
                <div className="pt-4">
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/signup", {
                            username,
                            firstName,
                            lastName,
                            password
                        });
                    }} label={"Sign Up"}/>
                </div>
                <ButtonWarning label={"Already have an account?"} buttonText={"Sign in"} to={"/signin"} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

here is the my backend database.js code:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/paytm');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        minLength: 3,
        maxLength: 30
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength: 50
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength: 50
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 6
    },
});

const accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }

})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

module.exports ={
    User,
    Account
};

i tried adding
<Button onClick={() => {
                        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/signup", {
                            username,
                            firstName,
                            lastName,
                            password
                        },{
                            headers: {
                                 "Content-type": "application/json"
}
});
                    }} label={"Sign Up"}/>

i want my frontend to hit backend correctly

Don’t store passwords in clear text
